# SQL Server replication between standard and developer editions

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2019

I have one SQL Server Standard (2019), I want to add one server for development (not used for production so the Developer edition); is it possible to replicate data from the Standard edition? What is the best method?

I want one way to have a server with production data only to test our batch. Is the replication between the standard and developer editions technically possible?

For licenses I think it's not a problem because only batch for test will connect this.

I have never used replication in SQL Server.

Comment: What kind of "batches" will you want to test?  Will it be read-only queries? If not, replication is probably not good for your scenario.  Modifying replicated tables on the subscriber will most likely break replication.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the second server is also the 2019 version, then I don't think you'll have any issues technologically.

But you have to be careful not violate your licensing agreement with Microsoft by using the Developer edition server for any production purpose. I'd recommend speaking to Microsoft or your Microsoft var to verify that side of things.

To your follow up question on which type of replication you should use, it depends on your use case and requirements:

1. [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver16) is probably the most commonly used kind. It is very configurable and flexible, and it replicates changes in near-realtime. (It replicates only the changes after the initial snapshot is synchronized.) One of the biggest requirements to use it is that any replicated tables need a primary key defined on them. A workaround for this is to create an indexed view which is applicable for replication because of its unique clustered index.
2. [Snapshot Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-replication?view=sql-server-ver16) is probably the next most commonly used kind of replication. It can be scheduled to run at a frequency of your choice but it drops and re-creates the entities being replicated, every time. This makes it a heavier type of replication than Transactional, and usually is not used for realtime synchronization.
3. [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver16) is another form of replication similar to Transactional, and can be used for realtime synchronization. I don't believe it has the same requirements as Transactional, in the sense that it can replicate tables without primary keys on them. But it has its own requirements. It's also useful for when your Subscriber database needs to be applicable for data changes that need to be propagated back to the Publisher, which is not usually possible with regular Transactional Replication (but I believe Transactional Replication with Updatable Subscriptions does allow this).
4. [Peer-to-Peer Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver16) is a fourth kind of replication that is also a type of Transactional Replication. (I never had a use case for it, so I don't know much about it, but please see the linked docs.)

Comment: If i have some tables without primary key i must to exclude the first solution (transactionnal réplication) ?
Size of my database is about 35Go.
Its the best solution for me ?
My need is only replicate one view from prod (sql server 2019) to dev.

Comment: I have many tables without PK and the Snapshot réplication can lock production database so it’s not good for me, i must use merge réplication ?

Comment: @user252985 Replication works at an object level. If you only need to replicate 1 view, then you don't need to select the rest of your database, only the objects that view depends on would need to exist on the Subscriber side. For Transactional, if any tables you need to replicate are missing primary keys (though that's bad database design and they all really should have primary keys) then you can create an indexed view on top of them and replicate that instead. In the replication properties you can have it rename the indexed view to the original table name on the Subscriber side.

Comment: Ok thanks, so i will test replicate this view from Production (SQL Server 2019 Standard) to test (SQL Server 2019 Developper).

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the term "Replication" loosely - meaning a way to somehow copy the whole thing. To this end, in you scenario I'd encourage you to explore log shipping, as opposed to Replication in the strictest sense.

Yes, SQL Server supports replciation in various guises (transational, etc) but it's awfully hard to set up, gets in the way of Availability Group and other current technologies, might limit your future production options.

Whereas, Log Shipping is easier to set up, copies the entire database from point A to B every 15 minutes (or every day, every night, however you choose) with minimal traffic. There's no need to set up distributor, etc.

Of course, you may not want the entire database for security and configuration reasons. But I'd still do log ship based solution over transactional replication based solution in your place. For example, you could have "MyApp" database on prod server exacltly mirrored warts and all into "MyApp" database every night at 2AM, so that when Devs come on in the morning it's yesterday's prod copy, always. But your devs would connect to "MyAppDevelopment" database which has its messy user accounts, free and clear of sensitive produciton logins, BUT - has "TheBigData" table referenced with three part refeerence in names, like there's

CREATE VIEW TheBigData
AS SELECT * FROM MyApp.dbo.TheBigData

so that applications seeking TheBigData table would be magically rerouted to the logshipped copy of production data, automatically refreshed every night. But everything else remains Dev, and you can have your messy dev/test data.

TO me, that beats dealing with nuances and limitations of Replication.